# Animated show with a main character named Nazire or Nasir who has a companion with dragon parents

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

It's been a while since I last viewed the animation. The name of the main character is a bit unclear, but it's either Nazire or Nasir. He hails from a royal background and was destined to meet his demise through a thunderstorm at a specific age due to being wrongly perceived as evil instead of the inherently good person he was supposed to be.

There's an opposing character, somewhat of a nemesis, who is always dressed in white. Eventually, they become friends to combat evil together. This opposing character's parents are dragons who are imprisoned in a location resembling hell, and they urge the white-clad character to eliminate Nazire, claiming that he took their place. However, the white-clad character, driven by their inherent goodness, consistently questions their dragon parents about why they want Nazire dead.

Everyone, including Nazire's parents, is aware of his extraordinary powers, and out of fear that he might inadvertently harm others, they kept him isolated from the rest of society.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. Specifically, was this a *movie*? What kind of *animation* was it (e.g. western animation, japanese anime?)

Comment: Obviously not the answer, but maybe there is some kind of connection: the classic SNES game Lagoon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagoon_(video_game)) has a hero named Nasir, with the opposing character named Thor, dressing blueish-white. IIRC, Thor's father wants Nasir dead but Thor is actually a good guy. The rest doesn't match, though.

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this, and did the show primarily use 2D (hand-drawn) or 3D (computer-generated) animation?

Comment: @AlexanderKlauer - One of the protagonists in *Royal Alchemist* (an otome video game) is Prince Nazire; https://t.vndb.org/sf/64/136364.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After lots of searching, I found the movie: ***[Ne Zha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ne_Zha_(2019_film))*** (2019).

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Animation/NeZha):

> *Ne Zha* (Chinese: 哪吒之魔童降世, Pinyin: *Nézhā zhī Mótóng Jiàngshì*) is a 2019 Chinese feature-length animated fantasy film. Featuring the popular Chinese mythological character Ne Zha, the plot is loosely based on the classic novel *Investiture of the Gods*, attributed to Xu Zhonglin.
>
> When a powerful creature of chaos was split into two parts, the Spirit Pearl and the Demon Pill, the Spirit Pearl was set to be merged with the third son of the hero Li Jing, while the Demon Pill was set to be destroyed by a massive lightning bolt in three years time.
>
> Machinations by the Dragons resulted in the Demon Pill being placed in the belly of Li Jing's wife, resulting in the birth of Ne Zha, a boy with great power and violent personality. Meanwhile, the Dragons merged the Spirit Pearl with one of their eggs, resulting in the birth of Ao Bing.

Comment: Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which is this site's way of showing that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, however, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.

Comment: Hi, it's great you found the answer!  You should expand this to describe a bit more about it, so the information is still available if the link goes dead.